# Import solders.pubkey could not be resolved, why Am I keep having this problem? besides installing solders and solana?

Tags: python, solana, solana-py

I am trying to websocket from solana to track transactions.
But am having problems when importing solders.
I have installed solana and solders correctly but somehow I keep receiving this error Import

```
"solders.pubkey" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource 

This is my code:
from solana.rpc.async_api import AsyncClient
from solana.rpc.websocket_api import connect
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey  # Usando Pubkey de solders
from solana.transaction import Transaction
```

I have tried reinstalling by force solana and solders but the problem persists my python version is above 3.7